# Starting Developing for Blackberry Playbook

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

I am a novice to blackberry development. I have quite a hands on experience in blackberry smartphones. After I heard a lot about blackberry playbook, now i want to enhance my skills towards it.

Please help me out how and where to start with ?

The tools or env setup ?

Comment: also, if your a C++ or Java developer. They are coming out with a blackberry player for the tablet with an SDK. [BlackBerry Tablet OS NDK](http://blackberrydevelopmenttalk.com/tag/blackberry-tablet-os-ndk/) It should be hitting limited Beta soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More useful resources to anybody looking in a similar scenario:

You may want to start [here](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/)

Playbook development is [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) based

also, if your a C++ or Java developer. They are coming out with a blackberry player for the tablet with an SDK. [BlackBerry Tablet OS NDK](http://blackberrydevelopmenttalk.com/tag/blackberry-tablet-os-ndk/) It should be hitting limited Beta soon.

Comment: For the NDK limited Beta, check [Apply to be part of the beta program at BlackBerry® Beta Zone](http://03268fe.netsolhost.com/bbbeta/)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Flex-for-the-BlackBerry-PlayBook-in-90-Minutes/ta-p/720803

Comment: @NEEL So out of curiosity, as a Java developer with experience in Blackberry smartphone development - you find a resource for Flex development more useful then the resource for C++ and Java I listed above.

Comment: @Ilya Berelson you give the good link. After supporting the c/c++, blackberry tablet become more powerfull.